# The relation between u and |u| in sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis

We know if $u\in W^{1,p}, (1\leq p\leq\infty)$, then $|u|\in W^{1,p}$. So, I would like to know if $|u|\in W^{1,p}, (1\leq p\leq\infty)$, then is $u\in W^{1,p}$? In addition, what is the relation between $u\in W^{s,p}$ and $|u|\in W^{s,p}$, (s is a any nonnegative real number, $1\leq p\leq\infty)$? What is relation between $u\in B^{s}_{p,q}$ (Besov Spaces) and $|u|\in B^{s}_{p,q}$, (s is a any nonnegative real number, $1\leq p\leq\infty)$? What is the relation u and |u| in other functional spaces? Thanks!

Comment: No, $\operatorname{sgn} x\not\in W^{1,p}[-1,1]$ but $1 \in W^{1,p}[-1,1]$

Comment: If $u \in W^{1,p}$ and $F$ is Lipschitz, then $F \circ u \in W^{1,p}$. This doesn't work in $W^{s,p}$ if $s > 1$ as $F$ isn't sufficiently regular.

Comment: @Calvin Khor : But if u is smooth, what is the relation between u and |u|?

Comment: @ Umberto P:  I have just found some results. If $0<s<1+\frac{1}{p}$, then $|||u|||_{B^s_{p,q}}\leq C||u||_{B^s_{p,q}}$ .

Comment: Your question is already incredibly wide before adding further that $u$ is smooth, which is not in the original question

Comment: @Calvin Khor : Thanks! In fact, we know that u is smooth in some sense in general. I would like to know more about tthe relation in this case.